# What is a good hashable python dict-like object for managing configuration parameters?

Tags: python, dictionary, caching, hashable

In order to cache functions (right now I'm using [klepto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/klepto) for that), I'm passing a confguration object `cfg` to the functions, s.t. the return value is only calculated, when `cfg` changes.

- Therefore, `cfg` has to be hashable and `hash(cfg1) == hash(cfg2)` if `cfg1 == cfg2`.
- I also would love to access the config parameters via dot-notation, e.g. `cfg.para1`.
- Nested entries would be nice, but one level is enough and I'm fine with `dict` and `list` being the only unhashable objects in `cfg`.

I want to do something like this:

```
from klepto import lru_cache
from klept.keymaps import hasher

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, cfg)
        self.cfg = cfg

    def my_func(self):
        return self._my_func(self.cfg)

    @lru_cache(keymap=hasher, ignore=(self,))
    def _my_func(self, cfg):
        a = cfg.a
        b = cfg.b.c[0]
        return expensive_func(a, b)

cfg_dic = {
    'a': 1, 
    'b': {'c': [1,2,3]}
}

cfg = give_me_the_hashable_object_i_need(cfg_dic)

my_obj = MyClass(cfg)

my_obj.my_func()    #evaluate only if cfg was not (recently) used before
```

#### First try

Use a `Box()` object from the package [python-box](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-box/), initialized by a regular (nested) python dict `cfg_dic`:

```
from box import Box
cfg = Box(cfg_dic, frozen_box=True, box_it_up=True)
```

#### Second try

Make `OrderedDicts` from `dic` and its entries (after turning it into tuples of tuples, ..) before initializing the `Box` like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from box import Box

def to_tuple(dic_or_list):
    l = []
    if isinstance(dic_or_list, list):
        for v in sorted(dic_or_list):
            try:
                hash(v)
                l.append(v)
            except TypeError:
                l.append(to_tuple(v))
    elif isinstance(dic_or_list, dict):
        for k, v in sorted(dic_or_list.items()):
            try:
                hash(v)
                l.append((k, v))
            except TypeError:
                l.append((k, to_tuple(v)))
    else:
        raise ValueError('argument must be one of "dict", "list"')
    return tuple(l)

def second_level_odict(tup):
    if len(tup) == 2:
        k_1, v_1 = tup
        if isinstance(v_1, tuple):
            for v_2 in v_1:
                if len(v_2) != 2:
                    return (k_1, v_1)
            return (k_1, (OrderedDict(v_1)))
        else:
            return (k_1, v_1)
    else:
        return tup

def first_level_odict(tup):
    l = []
    for t in tup:
        l.append(second_level_odict(t))
    return OrderedDict(l)

tup = to_tuple(dic)
odic = first_level_odict(tup)

cfg = Box(odic, frozen_box=True, box_it_up=True)
```

#### Third try

Abandon `box` and make the dict hashable.

```
class hashabledict(dict):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.items())))

class hashablelist(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self)))

def make_hashable(dic):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dic[k] = hashabledict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            dic[k] = hashablelist(v)
    return hashabledict(dic)
```

#### UPDATE Fourth try

I also tried passing the `cfg` `Box()` as a json-string with sorted keys:

```
def my_func(self):
    return self._my_func(self.cfg.to_json(sort_keys=True))

@lru_cache(keymap=hasher, ignore=(self,))
def _my_func(self, cfg_string):
    cfg =  Box().from_json(cfg_string)
    a = cfg.a
    b = cfg.b.c[0]
    return expensive_func(a, b)
```

All of which failed, because (e.g. after restarting the IPython kernel), the hash differs although the entries are the same.

I'm open for any suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am unclear on what your end goal is.  Could you give a simple example of what the expected behavior should be?

Comment: Thank you @James for your comment. I hope the code example makes it a bit clearer. Let me know if I can add more information.